# Merge two rows in a table in oracle with all same details apart from effective date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table Customer with below four columns

```
customer_id customer_effective_date customer_term_date service
1           1/1/2017                1/31/2017          Bike
1           2/1/2017                12/31/2017         Bike
1           1/1/2018                1/31/2018          Car
1           2/1/2018                2/28/2018          Car
1           3/1/2018                3/31/2018          Bike
1           4/1/2018                4/30/2018          Bike
```

I am trying to merge these to as below:

```
1           1/1/2017                12/31/2017          Bike
1           1/1/2018                2/28/2018          Car
1           3/1/2018                4/30/2018          Bike
```

Can anyone suggest how can we achieve this. i tried to group by and take min and max dates, but since the service for first record is Bike, i am getting the result as

```
1           1/1/2017                4/30/2017         Bike
1           1/1/2018                2/28/2018          Car
```

I need some headsup on this how can we do it.

Comment: Show us your current query attempt!

Comment: Why do you expect 3 rows returned and not 2? What is the logic in your merge of rows?

Comment: What defines the order of your records?  the Customer_effective_Date?  This appears to be an Islands & Gap Problem.

Comment: The main purpose of this is to clean up unnecessary records in between. For which i have to make sure i maintain the same sequence with effective date. As per the need, i need to maintain 3 records

Answer (score 2):

This is a gap-and-islands problem.  I'm not sure what the real logic is (do the dates have to overlap, as they do in the question?), but one approach is the difference in row numbers:

```
select customer_id,
       min(customer_effective_date),
       max(customer_term_date),
       service
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid order by customer_effective_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid, service order by customer_effective_date) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t
group by customer_id, (seqnum_s - seqnum), service
order by 2;
```

Comment: Nice, This solution is more general without depending strictly on date.

Comment: This is Nice. What if we have many columns, for Ex: if we have service1, service2, service3? How can this be handled

Comment: @Harikrishnamv . . . I don't understand the comment.  You should ask *another* question and provide sample data and desired results.  This question already has more than one answer.  Changing it could invalidate the answers.

Answer (score 1):

This will get your desired output if you also group by the year:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01f70/12)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  customer_id,
  customer_effective_date,
  customer_term_date,
  service
) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-01', DATE '2017-01-31', 'Bike' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2017-02-01', DATE '2017-12-31', 'Bike' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2018-01-01', DATE '2018-01-31', 'Car' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2018-02-01', DATE '2018-02-28', 'Car' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2018-03-01', DATE '2018-03-31', 'Bike' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2018-04-01', DATE '2018-04-30', 'Bike' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       MIN( customer_effective_date ) AS customer_effective_date,
       MAX( customer_term_date ) AS customer_term_date,
       service
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       customer_id,
       service,
       TRUNC( customer_effective_date, 'YYYY' )
ORDER BY
       customer_effective_date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01f70/12/0)**:

```
| CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMER_EFFECTIVE_DATE |   CUSTOMER_TERM_DATE | SERVICE |
|-------------|-------------------------|----------------------|---------|
|           1 |    2017-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-12-31T00:00:00Z |    Bike |
|           1 |    2018-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-02-28T00:00:00Z |     Car |
|           1 |    2018-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-04-30T00:00:00Z |    Bike |
```

**Query 2**:

This will also merge the groups, if it is an islands and gaps problem, and does it without aggregation:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT customer_id,
         LAST_VALUE( customer_effective_date )
           IGNORE NULLS OVER (
             PARTITION BY customer_id, service
             ORDER BY COALESCE( customer_effective_date, customer_term_date )
           ) AS customer_effective_date,
         customer_term_date,
         service
  FROM   (
    SELECT customer_id,
           CASE
           WHEN customer_effective_date
                  = LAG( customer_term_date, 1 ) OVER (
                      PARTITION BY customer_id, service
                      ORDER BY customer_effective_date
                    ) + 1
           THEN NULL
           ELSE customer_effective_date
           END AS customer_effective_date,
           CASE
           WHEN customer_term_date
                  = LEAD( customer_effective_date, 1 ) OVER (
                      PARTITION BY customer_id, service
                      ORDER BY customer_effective_date
                    ) - 1
           THEN NULL
           ELSE customer_term_date
           END AS customer_term_date,
           service
    FROM   table_name
  )
)
WHERE  customer_term_date IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY customer_effective_date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01f70/12/1)**:

```
| CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMER_EFFECTIVE_DATE |   CUSTOMER_TERM_DATE | SERVICE |
|-------------|-------------------------|----------------------|---------|
|           1 |    2017-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-12-31T00:00:00Z |    Bike |
|           1 |    2018-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-02-28T00:00:00Z |     Car |
|           1 |    2018-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-04-30T00:00:00Z |    Bike |
```